# use oracle extract regular expression match the last appeared year in result

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have some record like these:

> 1995,no.4-6;1996,no.1,4
>
> 1977,no.1-2;1978,no.1-3;1979,no.1-4

I want to extract last appeared year in those record. eg. 1996 in first record, 1979 in second record. I use

> regexp_substr(record, '\d{4}')

but I only get the first appeared year in each record. How could I get the last appeared year?

Comment: You can use simple `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[0-9]{4}[^;]*$
```

You can try this regex.you can extract the the `\d{4}` from this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/2

Comment: `\d` is not part of ERE, AFAIK. Use `[0-9]` is safer.

Comment: thanks, it works with regexp_substr(regexp_substr(record, '\d{4}[^;]*$') , '\d{4}')

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix.htm#g693775) is a bit scarce on what is allowed. I don't see in any documentation that ERE by itself can match `\d`, but the implementation is free to provide extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simple `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` implementation.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT q'[1995,no.4-6;1996,no.1,4]' str FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT q'[1977,no.1-2;1978,no.1-3;1979,no.1-4]' FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT SUBSTR(str, instr(str, ';', -1, 1)+1, 4) lst_yr
  7  FROM DATA
  8  /

LST_
----
1996
1979

SQL>
```